# Took more than X seconds to receive data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two million documents in one collection in mongodb. I'm trying to optimize my query.

I have a query like this:

```
Question
.where(
  topic: {'$in': ["stress", "pregnant", "smoking", "cancer", "warts"]},
  _type: 'Question',
  is_closed: true,
  picked_up_by_id: {'$ne': nil},
  is_anonymous: false,
  is_deleted: false
)
.order_by(updated_at: :desc)
```

`Question` has subclasses, so I use `_type` in my query to specify the name (type) of the class.

I tried to index using `hint` like this:

```
Question
.where(
  topic: {'$in': ["stress", "pregnant", "smoking", "cancer", "warts"]},
  _type: 'Question',
  is_closed: true,
  picked_up_by_id: {'$ne': nil},
  is_anonymous: false,
  is_deleted: false
)
.order_by(updated_at: :desc)
.hint({
  topic: 1,
  _type: 1,
  is_closed: 1,
  picked_up_by_id: 1,
  is_anonymous: 1,
  is_deleted: 1,
  updated_at: -1
})
```

but I still get timeout.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you actually have a suitable index on that collection?

Comment: What does your `Question` model look like? Have you defined an index in there? Something like `index({ _type: 1, topic: 1 })` should help.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, my index not suitable index, I have try a new index and now I don't get any error..